# Can you tell me about the correct usage of "over here" and "right here"?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I have already read an article at [Source](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/176047-here-right-here-over-here-there-right-there-over-there).

I wondered if I'm playing a board game, let it be Ludo.A storm comes and blows out the dices. I want to say that my dice was at this specific location(a box) on the board.Then I would say my dice was over here. But what would it mean if I say that my dice was right here?

Comment: Right here and right there are a bit more specific than over here, over there. But generally the difference is quite small, and my guess is that the expressions are used more or less interchangeably.

Comment: I'd say that *over here* implies that the listener is not "here" (i.e., the speaker is much closer to "here" than the listener). This implication doesn't apply to the case of *right here*. This is subtle, so in most situations the two are almost interchangeable, but I don't think they are completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of it as concentric circles where "right here/there" sits inside "over here/there".

"Here" is used to reference *something* close to you, "there" for *something* farther away.
"Right" is more specific than "over".

> right here

is usually used when the location is very specific, within reaching distance, and can be pointed to directly

[image: here]

> I'm right here

means "I am at this exact spot"

[image: here]

> I'm over here

means "I am at this general location" and is used to get the attention of the listener usually at a distance.

[image: here]

You would use "right here" if you were replacing your dice on the board yourself.