# "here" vs. "over here" in an area of an eye

Tags: meaning

I went through a post ([Can you tell me about the correct usage of "over here" and "right here"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/97036/109190)) and I guess I understand the explanation on it

> "right here/there" sits inside "over here/there"

A [tutorial](https://youtu.be/_K_v_CyhKp4?t=137) (00:02:23) seems to use the expression to convey another meaning

> ... the cornea over here ...

The area pointed out by the red circle is very close to the exact area of the cornea, which is along the blue one.

[image]

I guess the green one demonstrates inside while the blue one means next to. Is my understanding right? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear in what context the cornea is described as 'over here', unless it means 'over the surface of the eye'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for your reminder. I guess 'over the surface of the eye' is a reasonable context. I attached the link just now, would you please take a loot at that?

Comment: He's pointing at the Lacrimal gland (moving the cursor around the Lacrimal gland)... he said 'the Lacrimal gland over here'... (Kate is right ).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you. I am pretty sure his cursor is moving along the cornea at 00:02:23, though I am not that sure what "over here" refers to.

Comment: In simple terms, 'over here' means 'within your reach'.  (*Over here means near you* - From Collins English dictionary).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you. Does  'within your reach' [means this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/243455/109190)?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Please consider expanding your comments into an answer; otherwise, the question remains marked as "unanswered".

Comment: The speaker in the video is apparently Bosnian, so English isn't his first language. I don't know why he says 'over here'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's pointing at the *Lacrimal gland* (moving the cursor around the Lacrimal gland).

> He said '*the Lacrimal gland over here'*.

***[Over here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/over-here)*** means near you or in the country you're in. - Collins English dictionary

In simple words, 'over here' means *[within your (speaker) reach](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/within%20someone%27s%20reach)*, close enough to be touched or picked up by someone.

Comment: _Within your reach_ only if _you_ means the speaker. If you tell another person that something is _over here_, you mean that it is near you but not so near to them.